# Changing Shader on CCSprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0, kobold2d

I'm not sure why, but I am changing the Shader(CCGLProgram) on my sprite multiple times. I want to be able to use a previous Shader I allocated and used on the sprite, however doing so turns my entire sprite black (with no errors).

The only way I have found around this is by re-creating my programs and using the newly created ones instead. However, this is not ideal and I rather find a solution using the original program if possible.

Comment: You're not sure why you're changing the shader of your sprite? What do you mean by "recreating my programs"? Have you verified that the shader is working correctly (ie no errors)?

Comment: Yes, I have two shaders. I attach the first one, and later remove the first one and attach the second one. This works, everything looks as it should, but when I attach the first one again later my screen goes black. However, if I allocate a new CCGL program (with the same vertex and fragment shaders as the first one) and attach that one, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to u_mvpMatrix in one of your vertex shaders? Depending on the version of Cocos2d you're using you may need to change this to CC_MVPMatrix